# How to identify dynamic elements with available partial string to search for

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My dynamic HTML

< tabindex="2" id="cllink-12671-1A-0" href="javascript:availFareEnq($('#cllink-12671-1A-0'),'12671','Mon Feb 08 00:00:00 IST 2016','1A','MAS','ED',true)">1A

I have to identify this element by available strings "12671"&&"1A". Almost doing a LIKE command to search string.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the id contains "12671"

```
driver.findElement(By.cssselector("[id*='12671']"));
```

Or by text

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("1A"));
```

And if you want both you can use xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, '12671') and contains(text(), '1A')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a HTML tag which contains a href property, for which "12671" and "1A" will always be present in its value. You can use contains function for such things:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@href,'12671') and contains(@href,'1A')]"));
```

Hope it helps :)